# I need to create a new subdomain

Tags: nginx

I am working with Nginx and I need to create a new subdomain.

For mobile I have this

```
listen 80;
server_name www.bettors.com;
root   /home/helloWorld/MobileApp/www;
```

and for desktop

```
listen 80;
server_name www.desktop.bettors.com;
root   /home/helloWorld/webApp/dist;
```

but I want to change the `server_name` part in desktop and put `www.desktop.bettors.com`, I just changed the name in the Nginx console, I stop the server and started again, and Chrome is giving be an error:

**`this web page is not available`**

what can I do to create this new subdomain ? any ideas ?

Comment: Check nginx logs. Your configuration is pretty confusing, based on what you provided I don't know which of versions (mobile or desktop) nginx serving to users, because both `server` blocks are completely legit for `www.bettors.com`.

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov the ```server_name``` for desktop is: ```www.desktop.bettors.com;```, see the question please, I just updated

Comment: You have `www.desktop.bettors.com` in your config and want to change it to `www.desktop.bettors.com`? I don't see a problem there, they're identical.

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov yes i know, but once i enter to ```www.desktop.bettors.com``` it doesn't work, the comes up with a message ```this web page is not available```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a separate block for each server? I've always created my subdomains with a block for each subdomain.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    root /var/www/domain.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    root /var/www/sub.domain.com;
    ...
}
```